# Ansible: firewalld and adding new zone

Tags: ansible, firewalld

I' trying to add the following to an Ansible playbook:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --new-zone dockerc
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone dockerc --add-source 172.17.0.0/16
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone dockerc --add-port 8443/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone dockerc --add-port 53/udp
```

But according to http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/firewalld_module.html zones  do not have an option to add a new zone.

Does anyone know if its possible to add `dockerc` as a new zone using Ansible?

Comment: You can always just run firewall-cmd using the command or shell modules

Comment: @Magick Could you maybe change the accepted answer? The currently accepted is not valid anymore. The module can now create new zones. I just tested it (the second answer). Thanks :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As of 2017-12-12, specifically commit [`8475171f67f`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/commit/8475171f67f5346f79f55ddf30eb90c72a4f659a#diff-e5a231d51016543fc74a2f2a5b59209c), the firewalld module supports the creation (and deletion) of zones.

```
- firewalld:
    zone: custom
    state: present
    permanent: true
```

Set `state` to `present` or `absent`, and ensure that `zone`, `state`, and `permanent` are the only keys in the task.

Notes from the [source code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/8475171f67f5346f79f55ddf30eb90c72a4f659a/lib/ansible/modules/system/firewalld.py#L94-L99)

> - Zone transactions (creating, deleting) can be performed by using only the zone and state parameters "present" or "absent".
>     Note that zone transactions must explicitly be permanent. This is a limitation in firewalld.
>     This also means that you will have to reload firewalld after adding a zone that you wish to perfom immediate actions on.
>     The module will not take care of this for you implicitly because that would undo any previously performed immediate actions which were
>     not
>     permanent. Therefor, if you require immediate access to a newly created zone it is recommended you reload firewalld immediately after
>     the zone
>     creation returns with a changed state and before you perform any other immediate, non-permanent actions on that zone.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately the firewalld module is not suited for creating new zones. If the `firewall-cmd` is available on your host, then you can simply just run it separately:

```
- command: firewall-cmd --permanent --new-zone dockerc
```

Once the zone is set up you can use the module normally:

```
- firewalld:
    zone: dockerc
    permanent: true
    source: 172.17.0.0/16
    state: enabled
```

If you can't use the `firewall-cmd` command separately, then you are probably out of luck, as checking the [source code of the module](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/system/firewalld.py) you can see that it doesn't contain code to create new zones.

Note however that this module is a Curated module inside ansible, meaning that it doesn't get full Core support. If you know python, then you are welcome to send a pull request to make this module capable of creating new zones.